# House Deneith mercenaries

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, eberron

In Eberron during "The Last War" House Deneith, like all dragonmarked houses remained neutral and sold their services to the highest bidders. But as mercenaries/soldiers this could lead to some unique problems.

While these 2 situations appear different, their core problem is the same. Were either of these (or similar) situations addressed in any official material?

1. What would happen if 2 opposing countries had hired House Deneith soldiers in their units on the same battlefield? Would they fight themselves or did they have some contractual limitations to their services that excluded such a possibility?
2. While I'm sure House Deneith mercs were expensive, at times it could potentially be more cost efficient to lose them than a country's own citizens/soldiers they'd spent time/$ training and which would still be needed later in the war. Therefore, if presented a situation where heavy losses would be expected (think D-Day or worse) could they/were they ever ordered to (near) certain death? Was there some sort of financial penalty for mass losses? (This is the only penalty I can think of to prevent such tactics)

Comment: You're asking 2 totally different questions in one question. You should edit one of them out and ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @V2Blast It looks that way at 1st glance, while they cover 2 different scenarios they are, at their heart the same contract/lore question. Duplicate posts would be literal copy/paste redundant with likely the same answer applicable to both. I hate question/post spam and while on its face they appear separate, for the reasons above I think this would definitely fall into that category

Comment: They are related topics, sure, but they are quite different questions. "What happens if 2 different groups hire members of this mercenary group" is definitely not the same question as "were the mercenaries ever ordered to (near) certain death, and if so, how did they deal with it?" If neither of them is actually the problem you're trying to have answered, then you should ask your real question directly. It's easier for others to solve your problem if you explain what it actually is.

Comment: Also, there's no limit to the number of questions you can ask. Given that the two questions aren't identical, there's no harm in asking them separately.

Comment: These two questions in one post run a very high risk of answers only answering one and ignoring the other, because answers to one aren’t connected to the other. That’s one reason why a post like this with multiple questions will be held.

Comment: I can't delete this from my phone. Plz hide/delete. Thx